# Dots and Boxes with apha-beta pruning

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, game-development, alpha-beta-pruning

I have a problem with writing a dots and boxes game with alpha-beta pruning. The whole program works,  but the algorithm makes some stupid moves sometimes and I think it generates wrong evaluation of the state. Could you please look at it and maybe tell me what have I done wrong? I'm completely stuck at it.
(I know this code might be a little to chaotic and not optimized. If you have some suggestions to improve it in this area to, please give me some tips :) )

```
class MinMax:
    '''a class containing Min-Max algorithm
    it uses recursion to evalueate given state (node)'''
    def __init__(self, depth) -> None:
        '''define hiperparameters of the algorithm'''
        self._depth = depth

    @property
    def depth(self):
        return self._depth

    def solve(self, state, alfa=-float('inf'), beta=float('inf'), depth=None):
        '''solver using MinMax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning'''
        if depth is None:
            depth = self.depth
        children = state.generate_children()

        if len(children) == 0 or depth == 0:
            return state.evaluation

        if state.player == 1:  # max turn
            for child in children:
                if state.player == child.player:
                    alfa = max(alfa, self.solve(child, alfa, beta, depth))
                else:
                    alfa = max(alfa, self.solve(child, alfa, beta, depth-1))
                if alfa >= beta:
                    return beta
            return alfa
        else:  # min turn
            for child in children:
                if state.player == child.player:
                    beta = min(beta, self.solve(child, alfa, beta, depth))
                else:
                    beta = min(beta, self.solve(child, alfa, beta, depth-1))
                if alfa >= beta:
                    return alfa
            return beta
```

```
from __future__ import annotations
import numpy as np
import copy


class DostsAndBoxesState:
    def __init__(self, player: bool, dimentions: int, state=None, evaluation=0) -> None:
        '''class representing a single Node
        ::player: 0 for Min, 1 for Max
        ::state: state of the game in the node
        ::dimentions: dims of the game board
        '''
        self.player = player
        self.dimentions = dimentions
        self.evaluation = evaluation
        if not state:
            self.state = self.generate_first_state()
        else:
            self.state = state

    def generate_first_state(self):
        state = []
        for i in range(2*self.dimentions - 1):
            if i % 2 == 1:
                state.append(np.full(self.dimentions, -1))
            else:
                state.append(np.full(self.dimentions - 1, -1))
        return state

    def generate_children(self) -> None:
        '''
        children: states one state under current state
        while generating, it makes the evaluation based on evaluation of the parent and potentialy found box
        '''
        childen = []
        for row_index, row in enumerate(self.state):
            for connection_index, connection in enumerate(row):
                if connection == -1:
                    child = copy.deepcopy(self.state)
                    new_row = copy.deepcopy(row)
                    new_row[connection_index] = self.player  # zamieniam -1 na gracza
                    child[row_index] = new_row
                    boxes = self.find_box(row_index, connection_index)
                    if boxes:
                        component = len(boxes) if self.player else -len(boxes)
                        evaluation = self.evaluation + component
                        childen.append(DostsAndBoxesState(self.player, self.dimentions, child, evaluation))
                    else:
                        childen.append(DostsAndBoxesState(not self.player, self.dimentions, child, self.evaluation))
        return childen

    def find_box(self, row_index, column_index) -> np.array[list[np.array]]:
        '''
        looks for the boxes from up, down, left and right
        return array of booleans up_down / left_right
        '''
        boxes = []
        if row_index % 2 == 0:
            up_down = [0 if row_index == 0 else 1,
                       0 if row_index == (2*self.dimentions - 1) - 1 else 1]
            for indx, direction in enumerate(up_down):
                if direction == 1:  # if it's possible to go either up or down
                    row1 = row_index+2*((-1)**(indx+1))
                    row2 = row_index+1*((-1)**(indx+1))
                    if self.state[row1][column_index] != -1 and \
                        self.state[row2][column_index] != -1 and \
                            self.state[row2][column_index+1] != -1:
                        boxes.append(True)
        else:
            left_right = [0 if column_index == 0 else 1,
                          0 if column_index == self.dimentions - 1 else 1]
            for indx, direction in enumerate(left_right):
                if direction == 1:  # if it's possible to go either left or right
                    column = column_index-1 if indx == 0 else column_index
                    if self.state[row_index][column] != -1 and \
                        self.state[row_index-1][column] != -1 and \
                            self.state[row_index+1][column] != -1:
                        boxes.append(True)
        return boxes

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        '''
        prints out the state
        '''
        result = ""
        for index, row in enumerate(self.state):
            if index % 2 == 1:
                symbols = [' ' if connection == -1 else '|' for connection in row]
                line = [symbol+" " for symbol in symbols]
                str_line = "".join(line)
                result = result + str_line + "\n"
            else:
                symbols = [' ' if connection == -1 else '-' for connection in row]
                line = ["*"+symbol for symbol in symbols]
                str_line = "".join(line) + "*"
                result = result + str_line + "\n"
        return result
```

```
from __future__ import annotations
from time import sleep
from copy import deepcopy
from random import random
import numpy as np

from State import DostsAndBoxesState
from MinMax import MinMax


class DotsAndBoxes:
    def __init__(self, dimentions, depth, player_mode=1) -> None:
        self.dimentions = dimentions
        self.minmax_evaluator = MinMax(depth)
        self.player_mode = player_mode
        self.first_state = DostsAndBoxesState(1, self.dimentions)

    def bot_make_move(self, state, children):
        '''
        makes a move based on alpha-beta pruning from MinMax class
        '''
        if state.player:
            the_best_move = -float('inf')
            for new_state in children:
                evaluation = self.minmax_evaluator.solve(new_state)
                if evaluation == the_best_move:
                    draw = random()
                    state = new_state if draw < 0.5 else state
                elif evaluation > the_best_move:
                    the_best_move = evaluation
                    state = new_state
        else:
            the_best_move = float('inf')
            for new_state in children:
                evaluation = self.minmax_evaluator.solve(new_state)
                if evaluation == the_best_move:
                    draw = random()
                    state = new_state if draw < 0.5 else state
                elif evaluation < the_best_move:
                    the_best_move = evaluation
                    state = new_state
        return state

    def player_make_move(self, state):
        '''player's move'''
        player_move = [float('inf'), float('inf')]
        while True:
            player_move = input("Make your move: ").split(",")
            try:
                player_move = [int(player_move[0]), int(player_move[1])]
            except Exception:
                player_move = [float('inf'), float('inf')]
                continue
            try:
                if state.state[int(player_move[0])][int(player_move[1])] != -1:
                    player_move = [float('inf'), float('inf')]
                    continue
            except IndexError:
                player_move = [float('inf'), float('inf')]
                continue
            break
        state.state[int(player_move[0])][int(player_move[1])] = self.player_mode
        if not state.find_box(int(player_move[0]), int(player_move[1])):
            state.player = not state.player
        return state

    def check_scored(self, state, previous_state, message, score):
        '''if the box has been just compleated'''
        for index, row in enumerate(state.state):
            difference = np.where(row != previous_state.state[index])[0]
            if len(difference) != 0:
                box = state.find_box(index, difference[0])
                if box:
                    print(message)
                    score[state.player] += len(box)
                    break

    def play(self):
        '''
        the game itself
        '''
        state = self.first_state
        score = [0, 0]
        player_name = "Max" if self.player_mode else "Min"
        print(f"Welcome to the game, you are playing as {player_name}")
        while True:
            if state.player:
                # Max turn
                message = "Max scored!"
                children = state.generate_children()
                if len(children) == 0:
                    break
                print(state)
                print('\n')
                previous_state = deepcopy(state)
                if self.player_mode:
                    state = self.player_make_move(state)
                else:
                    state = self.bot_make_move(state, children)
                self.check_scored(state, previous_state, message, score)

            if not state.player:
                # Min turn
                message = "Min scored!"
                children = state.generate_children()
                if len(children) == 0:
                    winner = "Max"
                    break
                print(state)
                print('\n')
                previous_state = deepcopy(state)
                if not self.player_mode:
                    state = self.player_make_move(state)
                else:
                    state = self.bot_make_move(state, children)
                self.check_scored(state, previous_state, message, score)

        # Who won?
        print(state)
        if score[0] == score[1]:
            print("Tie!")
        else:
            winner = "Max" if score.index(max(score)) == 1 else "Min"
            print(f"The winner is: {winner}")
```

The algorithm is making stupid decisions, there might be something wrong with the evaluation function...?

Comment: I'll be really thankful for any suggestions and answers

Comment: There are some things you can do yourself: look for game state where the algorithm clearly makes a wrong move. Don't stop at finding one such state, but keep looking with states that are on smaller boards and closer to the end of the game (because they are easier to debug). Then add `print` calls in your `solve` function that *indent* with more spaces the lesser the `depth` is, so that the output is the search tree. Analyse and debug. Then if that doesn't give you insight into the cause, come back and share your debugging efforts and results.